# Do more questions need to be closed?

Tags: discussion

Am I the only one that thinks the site quality would be higher if more questions would be closed?

ps. I don't mean to offend the mods, it's a lot of work to manage, just wanted to get some input.

Comment: **YES** (filler text)

Answer (score 8):

I agree entirely. That said: I think the site/network mechanics should be allowed to work as intended. In other words: *if you want more questions closed, then vote to close more questions*.

Is this link available to all users, or only to those with moderator tools privileges and above?
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/close?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=day

If available to everyone, then I would encourage more frequent perusal of this list, and more concurring vote-casting.

#### Edit

Based on Rarst's comments below, I have an additional suggestion: unless/until either WPSE has enough users with close-vote privileges *who exercise those privileges*, or the SE network requirements change so as to facilitate community policing of questions in need of closing, why not just implement a *de facto* practice for WPSE, whereby **moderators automatically close questions with 3 close votes**?

(Or 4 votes. Or 2 votes. Including/not including the moderators' own vote. Whatever we think is reasonable for our given circumstances.)

Comment: From discussion in chat "close" tab in review seems to be most restrictive, so probably needs 10K rep to unlock.

Comment: Is there any way that it can be made less-restrictive, so that it is visible to anyone with close-vote privileges?

Comment: Not in my powers (as usual).

Comment: Is this a suggestion for SO meta? Or is it (yet another) issue that results from the relative youth of WPSE, and the dearth of high-exp users?

Comment: We are supposed to raise issues locally first anyway. I made a fuss (and a lot of it) in moderator chat today that we have issues that just get worse. Among other things I asked for more attention to our meta and hopefully someone from higher powers will get to going through it in near future.

Comment: See updated answer. Maybe the correct answer at this time is that we take matters into our own hands?

Comment: Yes I think that is part of the problem in terms of management, only 6 users can see that page, and only about 20-25 people can vote to close questions which in turn requires 4 votes.

Comment: Re:edit the problem with "automatically" is that it's not automatic. It needs attention and manual action from moderator. Mods are currently spread very thin and that's another issue, that I also raised yesterday and that will be dealt with.

Comment: @StackExchange - Please allow `/review/close` to be viewed by users that have close permission. Yours truly. Brady

Comment: Added this as a [feature request](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/877/251) Please feel free to add additional arguments for the request.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

We don't have enough users capable of voting to close and doing that actively. Takes [3000 rep to vote](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions) (a little over twenty users have that much) and 5 users to get it closed.

I think it was brought up more than once that SO-based requirements for some things don't quite work, but nothing came out of it.

It seems that access to close review queue is quite restrictive so here is current state of close flags for perspective:

[Close votes http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=1:|x5|x4|x3|x2|x1&chxr=0,0,120&chxt=x,y&chbh=a&chs=300x150&cht=bhs&chds=0,134&chd=t:134,26,2,0,0&chtt=Close+votes](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=1:|x5|x4|x3|x2|x1&chxr=0,0,120&chxt=x,y&chbh=a&chs=300x150&cht=bhs&chds=0,134&chd=t:134,26,2,0,0&chtt=Close+votes)

[Close reasons http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=1:|not+a+real+question|not+constructive|exact+duplicate|too+localized|off+topic&chxt=x,y&chbh=a&chs=300x150&cht=bhs&chd=t:100,35,29,22,3&chtt=Close+vote+reasons](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=1:|not+a+real+question|not+constructive|exact+duplicate|too+localized|off+topic&chxt=x,y&chbh=a&chs=300x150&cht=bhs&chd=t:100,35,29,22,3&chtt=Close+vote+reasons)

As you see pretty much nothing reaches 5 close votes even closely.

Answer (score 0):

To echo Chip, if you think something should be closed, *vote to close it.*

Moderators should not (and will not) unilaterally close posts unless they're so far off base there can be no argument made to keep them open.  Even then, we'll usually leave a comment or note to that effect and encourage the OP to edit their question.

But if 2 or 3 people have already voted to close something before I come across it, I'll add my vote and immediately close it.  Just flagging it for moderator attention isn't enough.  You should also vote to close so that we know you're serious.

Ironically, I hear this complaint (that we don't close enough posts) most often from people with >3k rep ... who also aren't voting to close things on their own.