# Allow users with "vote to close" privileges access to the review/close tab

Tags: feature-request

The new review section is very helpful for identifying questions and answers that might otherwise go unnoticed by higher rep users.  It would be more helpful if users with "vote to close" privileges had access to view questions with existing close votes.

As discussed in [Do more questions need to be closed?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/861/251) and [State of stack 2012](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/871/251) the user base of high rep users is not large enough to self moderate like some of the other SE sites and allowing this feature for users without 10k rep would help improve the quality of the site and take some of the burden off the moderators.

Comment: Ah, you can read my mind!

Comment: It would appear that the `close` tab was [once available to non-10k users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111838/why-was-review-close-taken-away-for-under-10k-users-can-it-be-put-back) but that no longer holds true.

Answer (score 4):

I totally agree with this and in both those questions mentioned I have asked for view of questions that have close votes.

Please please please Stack Exchange administrators add this feature.

Answer (score 2):

I had a go playing with data.stackexchange.com to see if I could get the data of close votes. Here is what I got:

http://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/query/61533/find-questions-with-close-votes

Works nicely but only disadvantage is that the data isn't real time and only gets updated now and then.

Comment: Onlyl problem: That data isn't live.

Comment: Yes I did mention that ;) The data is updated once a month so won't be long until that data is almost live :)